# vector of cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

My class contains a vector of cv::Mat images.

```
class reconstructed_object
{
    private:
    std::vector<cv::Mat> raw_images;

    public:
    reconstructed_object();
    show_images();
}
```

In its constructor 3 images from my harddrive are read using cv::imread("path") and pushed into the vector.

```
reconstructed_object::reconstructed_object()
{
    raw_images.push_back(cv::imread("path_1").clone());
    raw_images.push_back(cv::imread("path_2").clone());
    raw_images.push_back(cv::imread("path_3").clone());
}

void reconstructed_object::show_images()
{
    for (int i=0; i < raw_images.size(); i++)
    {
        cv::imshow("raw_image", raw_images[i]);
        cv::waitKey(1000);
    }
}
```

After reading all the suggestions about deep copy I used the "clone"-method. However the vector is filled with three times the image from "path_3". How can I save the different pictures in the vector?

Comment: looks fine to me, shouldn't even need the `clone()` as `imread` creates a new `Mat` each time. how are you checking the images?

Comment: I added the body of the show_images() method. Might it be a new bug in opencv3.1?

Comment: if you  cv::imshow("raw_image 1",cv::imread("path_1"); cv::imshow("raw_image 2",cv::imread("path_2"); cv::imshow("raw_image 3",cv::imread("path_3"); cv::waitKey(0); does it display 3 different images in 3 windows?

Comment: Not sure if I got you. You can save images by `cv::imwrite("pic.png",mat)` (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#bool%20imwrite(const%20string&%20filename,%20InputArray%20img,%20const%20vector%3Cint%3E&%20params)

Comment: The lines cv::imshow("raw_image 1",cv::imread("path_1"); cv::imshow("raw_image 2",cv::imread("path_2"); produce different images. But passing all Mats from the vector using cv::imshow("raw_image", raw_images[i]) only the last image is seen. I'm stuck because I have no clue how to avoid pushing solely the last image multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cv::imshow("raw_image"+ std::to_string(i), raw_images[i]);
```

I suggest that problem is that all your windows where you pass images have the same name. So, each next member of the vector just overlaps the images before.